# Masonry HTML/CSS created blocks float apart

Tags: javascript, html, css, masonry

I am working on a image collage for my website and have just tried to do it using masonry, but when I alter the size of the created blocks for some reason they float apart with big gaps between each block. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
/* ---- grid ---- */

.grid {
  border: 5px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #EEE;
  max-width: 1346px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
/* clearfix */

.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
/* ---- grid-item ---- */

.grid-item {
  width: 240px;
  height: 180px;
  background: #D26;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Masonry - Initialize in HTML</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Masonry - Initialize in HTML</h1>
  <div class="grid" data-masonry='{ "itemSelector": ".grid-item", "columnWidth": 160 }'>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
  </div>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='http://masonry.desandro.com/masonry.pkgd.js'></script>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

As it may not show up on there you will need to create a file for it in order to see what is going on. [image: Image of gaps]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change columnWidth to 0 in data-masonry.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
/* ---- grid ---- */

.grid {
  border: 5px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #EEE;
  max-width: 1346px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
/* clearfix */

.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
/* ---- grid-item ---- */

.grid-item {
  width: 240px;
  height: 180px;
  background: #D26;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Masonry - Initialize in HTML</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Masonry - Initialize in HTML</h1>
  <div class="grid" data-masonry='{ "itemSelector": ".grid-item", "columnWidth": 0 }'>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
  </div>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='http://masonry.desandro.com/masonry.pkgd.js'></script>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Okay I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe give a look at [Mason](https://github.com/DrewDahlman/Mason) which allows you to fills gapes in plugins like masonry, I never tested it though so give it a try and tell us what worked ;-)